# Authentication error upon running a shell script as sudo inside a flask application being run by uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, sudo, systemd

I'm using a shell script to restart my flask app upon receiving a webhook request from github, but I'm running into an issue with no-password sudo authentication, but only when `uWSGI` is runs the restart function.

I have the application deployed as a `systemd` service and in order to restart the service, I have to run `systemctl restart myapp.service` as `sudo`. So I stuck that line into a script, and marked it as runnable as sudo without password authentication in `/etc/sudoers` by the user that runs the webapp.

The restart function is very simple:

```py
import os


def on_push():
    os.setuid(os.geteuid())
    os.system('sudo /path/to/script.sh')
```

And the script itself is a one-liner:

```sh
systemctl restart myapp.service
```

Running the command via `os.system('sudo /path/to/script.sh')` in a normal python shell restarts the app as expected, without asking for the password. However, when the command is run by a `uWSGI` worker process, it fails to restart with the message that `Interactive authentication required`.

Is this an issue that can be solved by changing uWSGI launch parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to set `uid` and `gid` in the `.ini` file used to start the uWSGI instance to the user/group used to run the application.